# Oracle view ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, view, ora-00907

```
SELECT 
    SALE.SaleID,
    SALE.SaleDate,
    CUSTOMER.CustomerID, 
    FIRSTNAMEFIRST(Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName),
    SALE_ITEM.SaleItemID,
    SALE_ITEM.ItemID,
    ITEM.ItemDescription, 
    ITEM.ItemPrice
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN SALE ON CUSTOMER.CustomerID = SALE.CustomerID
INNER JOIN SALE_ITEM ON SALE.SaleID = SALE_ITEM.SaleID
INNER JOIN ITEM ON SALE_ITEM.ITEMID = ITEM.ItemID
```

Even when I test the view it'll show the correct query results but I can't figure out error ORA-00907.

Function definition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FIRSTNAMEFIRST 
    ( FIRSTNAME IN VARCHAR2, LASTNAME IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN TRIM(FIRSTNAME) || ', ' || TRIM(LASTNAME);
END;
```

Comment: What does the function FirstNameFirst look like?  Does it work when called elsewhere?

Comment: this is the function and I am able to call it elsewhere                              CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FIRSTNAMEFIRST (
    FIRSTNAME IN VARCHAR2,
    LASTNAME IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BEGIN
    RETURN TRIM(FIRSTNAME) || ', ' || TRIM(LASTNAME);
END;

Comment: I don't see any other parentheses in the code you pasted.  Do you get that error when you run your query?  Can you select data from each of the tables separately?

Comment: one thing is still missing. . . *"Even when I test the view. .  "* WHERE is the view?

Comment: We need to see the complete `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it worked after I added AS FullName after `FIRSTNAMEFIRST(Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName)`. Sorry if I didn't include enough info, Thanks.

Comment: sure, if you don't add column alias [this is what it's called], you might see issues calling it in some instances. In the query window oracle will simply return something like `FIRSTNAMEFIRST(Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName)` as column header. But you didn't provide us with full problem. Hence, you had to dig it yourself. Looks like you were building a view and view column name can't contain parenthesis. Something like that

Comment: We still don't know **HOW** you got ***ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis*** because if you try doing this `create or replace view MyFuncView as 
   select MyFunc('aaa', 'bbbb')  from dual`, you would get ***ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias
00998. 00000 -  "must name this expression with a column alias"*** hence you would quickly know that you need to add alias.